# Ruby mixin - accessing module instance variables in class instances

Tags: ruby, mixins

I'm pretty new to Ruby and seems that I'm still confused with mixin and including modules in classes. I would like to be able to access instance variables (@) defined in modules in classes.
I have the following piece of code:

```
module ModuleB
  attr_reader :b

  def ModuleB.initialize(browser)
    puts "initialize from ModuleB"
    @browser = browser
    @b = 5
  end
end

module ModuleA
  attr_reader :a
  include ModuleB

  def ModuleA.initialize(browser)
    ModuleB.initialize(browser)
    puts "initialize from ModuleA"
    @browser = browser
    @a = @b
  end

  def action_1
    @a = @b + 1
    return @a
  end
end

class ClassA
  include ModuleA
  def initialize(browser)
    ModuleA.initialize(browser)
    @browser = browser
    puts 'initialize - method in ClassA'
    @c = @a
    @d = @b
    puts "a = #{@a}"
    puts "b = #{@b}"
    puts "c = #{@c}"
    puts "d = #{@d}"
  end

end

s = 'hello'
instA = ClassA.new(s)
puts instA.action_1
```

And here's the output that I get:

```
initialize from ModuleB
initialize from ModuleA
initialize - method in ClassA
a =
b =
c =
d =
mixin_example2.rb:23:in `action_1': undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from mixin_example2.rb:46:in `<main>'
```

Seems like `@a` and `@b` are uninitialized.
Additional thing, is that I cannot use '+' operator in `action_1` method.
What did I miss?

Sorry if I repeated problem that might have already been raised but I didn't find an answer so far.

Comment: This seems like it should be an inheritance pattern not a module pattern. Using inheritance makes this smoother more functional and more obvious

Comment: mixin inheritance *is* inheritance, though. In fact, `include` simply creates a class and makes that class the superclass.

Comment: @engineersmnky, in fact what I'm trying to do (not shown in this piece of code) is to get multiple inheritance using modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instance variables belong to instances (which is why they are called "instance variables"). You have three objects of interest here, every single one of which has its own `@b` which has nothing to do with any of the other `@b`s of the other objects: `ModuleA` has its own `@b`, as does `ModuleB`, and `instA` also has its own `@b`.

Here is a more sensible implementation of what you are trying to do:

```
module ModuleB
  def initialize(browser)
    puts "initialize from ModuleB"
    @browser = browser
    @b = 5
  end
end

module ModuleA
  include ModuleB

  def initialize(browser)
    super
    puts "initialize from ModuleA"
    @a = @b
  end

  def action_1
    @a = @b + 1
  end
end

class ClassA
  include ModuleA

  def initialize(browser)
    super
    puts 'initialize - method in ClassA'
    @c = @a
    @d = @b
    puts "a = #@a"
    puts "b = #@b"
    puts "c = #@c"
    puts "d = #@d"
  end
end

s = 'hello'
instA = ClassA.new(s)
# initialize from ModuleB
# initialize from ModuleA
# initialize - method in ClassA
# a = 5
# b = 5
# c = 5
# d = 5
#=> #<ClassA:0x007f8b5f12e110 @a=5, @b=5, @browser="hello", @c=5, @d=5>

puts instA.action_1
# 6
```

Comment: Excellent answer although in my opinion still less obvious than a direct class to class inheritance pattern. Although I understand your point regarding inclusion's superclass injection.

Comment: Thank you very much @Jorg. That's very clean code that I needed. However, I don't get your comment that there are 3 instances of @b in the code above: one for ModuleA, one for ModuleB and one for ClassA. If I instantiate object from ClassA how do I access @b from modules that are included? Isn't it just a single @b accessible on ClassA instance from superclass?

Comment: Also, one more comment but I'll probably create new question: if classA in fact inherited from 2 modules (let's say there was additional ModuleC) through includes, how could both superclass initialize methods be called?

Comment: @PiotrGesicki: Instance variables belong to objects. Each object has its own set of instance variables that are completely private to that particular object. The instance variable `@foo` of object `a` is completely separate from the instance variable `@foo` of object `b`. In your code, there are three different objects, all of which have an instance variable `@b`: `ModuleA`, `ModuleB`, and `instA` all have an instance variable named `@b`. But they are three different objects. They have nothing to do with each other. The fact that you set instance variable `@b` of `ModuleA` to some value …

Comment: … has absolutely no effect whatsoever on the instance variable `@b` of object `ModuleB` or the instance variable `@b` of object `instA`.

Comment: @PiotrGesicki: `include` simply makes the module the superclass of the class you are including it into. That's it. (Okay, there's a bit more to it than that: if you `include` a module into a module, it obviously doesn't make it the superclass (modules don't have superclasses), but rather it makes a note that should the including module later be included into a class, the included module needs to be included as well.) So, you call it just like you would any other superclass method, using `super`. Remember: `initialize` is a method just like any other method, there is no such thing as a …

Comment: "constructor" in Ruby.

Comment: Ah, I just re-read your first comment. You wrote: "However, I don't get your comment that there are 3 instances of @b in the code above: one for ModuleA, one for ModuleB and one for **ClassA**." – I never said that. I said there are 3 instances of `@b` in the code above: one for `ModuleA`, one for `ModuleB`, and one for **`instA`**! Instance variables are always looked up relative to `self`. In line 7 of your code, `self` is `ModuleA`, so the instance variable `@b` gets assigned on `ModuleA`. In line 19, `self` is `ModuleB`, so `@b` gets looked up on `ModuleB`, which doesn't have it and thus …

Comment: … it is `nil`. On lines 23, 35, and 37 `self` is `instA`, which doesn't have an `@b` either, so again, it evaluates to `nil`.